# Why isn't Adobe Phonegap Build not including my plugin in the built apk?

Tags: cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, phonegap

I wrote a game using Intel XDK with Phaser framework. To get low latency audio playback I used cordova-plugin-nativeaudio. I checked the plugin folder and also config.xml, the plugin is included. But when I upload the zip build file to Adobe Phonegap, the core cordova plugins are included in the apk but not the one mentioned above. I checked the build log and even installed the apk on my phone but there was no audio. I have tried all three methods of Intel XDK for installing plugins namely npm, local and git repo. But all methods have the same result. Intel XDK installs  but Phonegap Build doesn't include it during build process. Also I can't build on my machine currently because I having some issues with Android Studio. I also checked the pricing plan & my plan does have the option of third party plugins. Any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem ?

Comment: I haven't worked with all the tools that you're using but it sounds like getting Android Studio to build properly is your best initial bet. Perhaps if you include more information on what issues Android Studio is having people can help troubleshoot that.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the config.xml file that is part of the ZIP package you are submitting to PhoneGap Build? Specifically, all of the `<plugin... />` tags in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My app's name contained a special character, an '&'. Had to replace it in the name tag.